C file not runnning in vscode
I have recently started learning c from the course provided by freecodecamp. So, I was writing a very simple program that takes age as input from user and displays you are - years old.
But when I try to run the code it gives the sign running but gives nothing as output. How could I resolve this?
Here is the code:
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   int age;
   printf("Enter your age:");

   scanf("%d",&age);

   printf("You are %d years old",age);

   return 0;
}


C is a compiled language, you need to compile it and then run the result.

Try this: https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler

Do you see the output if you add the line fflush(stdout); after the first printf statement?

VS Code is notoriosuly difficult to set up for a beginner. It also has several different windows where the output can appear "defpending". The question does not have enough info to tell what happened in your case.

In my view,VSCode is not a good tool for beginner,because it has not compile and  debug function if you do not install extension or other tools, i recommend you use the Clionenter link description here, I think this tool is very vell in C programming learning!

is this the op?
